# Angular import external module into every project module or only app?

Tags: angular, angular-module

I have an Angular app with 10 modules. Each time I install a new external package, I need to import it to every module that uses it. is it meant to work like so or there is a way to import it only once to app module ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, You should not be doing that. You can make use of `Shared` Module.
Create a `Shared` Module in your project and then import all the external modules within the `Shared` Module. So that you could only import `Shared` module in all your project modules.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#shared-module